# Thousand separator while typing in a tkinter Entry widget

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, separator

Can you help me to separate a number into thousands while typing on a tkinter label?

Comment: It’s not possible to type in a label widget.

Comment: To convert a number to a string with thousand separators: `format(number, ",d")`.

Answer (score 2):

1. First of all it is not possible to edit or insert any text in a Tkinter `label`. To insert text as input you have to use the `Entry` widget.
2. Secondly, The entry widget of Tkinter accepts text through `.get()` command which can only be used through a function. EXAMPLE: Here the input is being stored in the variable `L`

```
def funct():
    global L
    L = ENTRYbox.get()

ENTRYbox = Entry(root)
ENTRYbox.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.3, relx=0.2, rely=0.3)

BUTTON0 = Button(root, text="ACCEPT THE INPUT", command=funct)
BUTTON0.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, relx=0.6, rely=0.3)
```

3. As far as inserting separator of 1,000 value is concerned ,that can not be done while the user is typing into the `ENTRYbox`. However, when the user has pressed the button, the input gets stored in a variable (`L`) and that input can be executed in a loop to fill in 1,000 separators between each letter. EXAMPLE:

```
def funct():
    global L
    L = ENTRYbox.get()
    L = str(L)

ENTRYbox = Entry(root)
ENTRYbox.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.3, relx=0.2, rely=0.3)

BUTTON0 = Button(root, text="ACCEPT THE INPUT", command=funct)
BUTTON0.place(relwidth=0.5, relheight=0.1, relx=0.6, rely=0.3)


output = [""]
for i in L:
    sep = 1000*" "
    fst = L+sep
    output.append(fst)

print(output)
```

Hope it helps ......

Comment: `sep = 1000*" "` will create a string with 1000 spaces.  Is it really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple solution for this issue, if you just want to show the number with the 1000 seperators.

```
price = 234566788
sep_price = (f"{price:,}")
print(sep_price)
```